# how to show images as a gridview like format in uiscrollview in ios?

Tags: xcode, gridview, ios6, uiscrollview

its just a week that am into ios devlopement and am facing some problem that i cant show the images in scrolview with gridview format...i dont know how to set the frame size to show images in proper gridview format..

here is my code

that add 5 images in scrollview

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
            {
                UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+0, 0, 320, 460)];
                [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"e1%d.png",i]]];
                [scr addSubview:image];
                x+=320;
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
                tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                tapGesture.delegate = self;
                image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [image addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
            }

            scr.pagingEnabled=YES;
            scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*5, 300);
            [self.view addSubview:scr];
```

but all 5 images shows in one horizontal line but i want to show in every line 2 images.

Comment: Use UICollectionView instead.

Comment: actually its just a week i am into this...so if u can guide me with the above code with some changes then it will helpful a lot..

Comment: I don't have time for that now, sorry, that's why I didn't post a full answer, maybe someone else can. Check out the WWDC videos on UICollectionView though: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=205

Comment: ok..thanx for your response..will see that video

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution, i've implemented it in my app. Here is my code sv_port is my scrollView. Download SDWebImageDownloader class files and import it in your project. Add 
relevant framework in your project. like imageIO.framework, QuartzCore

if your images are not fetching from url, then u dont need to use asyncImage view., so dont need to download SDWebImageDownloader.

Now, in your .m add

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "SDImageCache.h"
#import "SDWebImageCompat.h"

//function for adding image in your scrollview
-(void)populateImages
{
   int x=6,y=6;

   for(UIView * view in sv_port.subviews)
   {
      if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
      {
          [view removeFromSuperview]; view = nil;
      }
      if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
      {
          [view removeFromSuperview]; view = nil;
      }
   }

   for(int p=0;p<[Manufacturer count];p++)
   {
      UIButton *btnImageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      btnImageButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,70,70);
      [btnImageButton setTag:p];
      [btnImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextview:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      UIActivityIndicatorView *spinny = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
   spinny.frame=CGRectMake(btnImageButton.frame.origin.x+25,btnImageButton.frame.origin.y+25, 20, 20);
      spinny.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
      [spinny startAnimating];

      [sv_port setScrollEnabled:YES];
      [sv_port addSubview:spinny];

      UIImageView *asyncImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:btnImageButton.frame] autorelease];
      asyncImageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
      CALayer *layer;
      layer = asyncImageView.layer;
      layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
      layer.cornerRadius = 5;
      layer.masksToBounds = YES;


      [asyncImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourUrl] ]   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] options:0 andResize:CGSizeMake(btnImageButton.frame.size.width,btnImageButton.frame.size.height) withContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
      asyncImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

      [sv_port addSubview:btnImageButton];
      [sv_port addSubview:asyncImageView];
      int imgCntPort=0;

      imgCntPort=(sv_port.frame.size.width/(asyncImageView.frame.size.width));

      //NSLog(@"imgport %d",imgCntPort);
      if((p+1)%imgCntPort==0)
      {
         x=5;
         y=y+80;
      }
      else
      {
         x=x+80;
      } 
    }
    sv_port.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, y);
    glob_x =0; glob_y =y;
}
```

By this code you will get 4 images in a row., By the change co-Ordiante of x and y you can maintain number of images per row to display.

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: thanx for your help...will implement it and let u know